# Using sed or awk how do you remove a pattern around a certian line

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I need to remove a pattern around a certain line:

```
#undef LZZ_INLINE
#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE
#include "somename.inl"
#endif
```

Should become:

```
#include "somename.inl"
```

I do not know `somename` in advance.
How can this be done using e.g. sed or awk in a generic fashion ?

Comment: Can't you make sure the `LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE` is defined instead?

Comment: The code as such is autogenerated by another tool. I could live with it but I want to clean it up and completely get rid of this LZZ preprocessor directive since I do not use it. So it's not a c++ problem as such but a text formatting problem. Since other people have to read the code and work with it, I do not want superfluous defines since they add complexity and clutter the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file size allows reading loading it in the memory all at once, you can do

```
sed -i.bk ':a;$!{N;ba}; s/#undef LZZ_INLINE\n#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE\n\(#include [^\n]*\)\n#endif/\1/g' input.file
```

Remove the `.bk` file if everything goes well :)

Comment: I need an in place solution so this is perfect !!

Comment: @Martin I'm glad that helped. You can use `-i` instead of `-i.bk` and `sed` will delete the "backup" automatically.

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit on what's going on with the `:a;$!{N;ba};` portion of the statement please?

Comment: @nullrevolution This part reads the whole file into the pattern space. It uses a _label_ `a`, which says "read in another string and branch unconditionally to `a`, unless on the last line". See more about flow control in `sed` [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-58).

Answer (score 2):

pls try if this oneliner would work for you:

```
awk '/#undef LZZ_INLINE/{next;} /#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE/{x=1;next;}x&&/#endif/{x=0;next;}1' file
```

Comment: One thing I should clarify: I need to perform this in a batch as in place edit if possible. Simply adding -F did not work (I'm not very familiar with awk)

Comment: @Martin, awk cannot edit inplace. You'll have to `awk '...' file > new && mv new file`

Comment: Slight correction, awk CAN edit in-place but you need to program it to do so. I'll post an example...

Answer (score 2):

add this to a file called fix.sed

```
/^#undef LZZ_INLINE/{
N
N
N
s/.*\(#include "[^"]*"\).*/\1/
}
```

run like this :

sed -f fix.sed your-original file

Comment: Your solution is efficient however you need to be explicit on the strings before and after the `#include` line otherwise you may incur false positives.

Comment: true. the original question said it was machine generated, so I figured you could count on the pattern, but you do raise a valid point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the answer @glennjackman posted:

```
awk '/#undef LZZ_INLINE/{next} /#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE/{x=1;next}x&&/#endif/{x=0;next} 1' file
```

is correct and you just want to update the input file in-place, here's one way you can do that with awk:

```
awk '/#undef LZZ_INLINE/{next} /#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE/{x=1;next}x&&/#endif/{x=0;next} {out[++nr]=$0} END{close(FILENAME); for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) print out > FILENAME}' file
```

(i.e. replace `1` with `{out[++nr]=$0} END{close(FILENAME); for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) print out > FILENAME}`)

Here's another:

```
awk '/#undef LZZ_INLINE/{next} /#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE/{x=1;next}x&&/#endif/{x=0;next} {print > "/tmp/\""FILENAME"\"" } END{system("mv /tmp/\""FILENAME"\" \""FILENAME"\""}' file
```

(i.e. replace `1` with `{print > "/tmp/\""FILENAME"\"" } END{system("mv /tmp/\""FILENAME"\" \""FILENAME"\""}`)

There's a few variations in how to implement it but the basic idea is just to buffer the output until you're done reading the input file then overwrite the input file. NBD either way...

One other variation I should mention is to create a tmp INPUT file, that'd look like this:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   tmp="/tmp/\"" ARGV[1] "\""
   while ( (getline var < ARGV[1]) > 0 ) {
      print var > tmp
   }
   close(tmp)
   out = ARGV[1]
   ARGV[1] = tmp
}
/#undef LZZ_INLINE/{next} /#ifdef LZZ_ENABLE_INLINE/{x=1;next}x&&/#endif/{x=0;next} {print > out}' file
```

Whether you use a system("mv...") or a getline loop is style or dependent on what your OS provides.